# Does Arjuna ever ask Krishna to prove Himself?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

In the Bhagavad Gita, Arjuna (or any of the others) doesn't ask for Krishna a proof of His supremacy/divinity/Godliness. He just assumes Krishna to be divine and correct.

Is there a dialogue (chapter and verse please) where Arjuna questions the authenticity of Krishna ?
When exactly does Arjuna come to believe that what Krishna says is the ultimate truth and not just His mendacity ?

Comment: In Gita, Arjuna asked about Krishna's supremacy...for example, see 4.4 shloka...11.3 shloka is related to ur another question...

Comment: Forgive me if this is incorrect, but I think he believes in Kṛṣṇá's divinity since before the events of Bhagavad Gita. I remember it being mentioned in Mahabharata before the battle. Certainly he is fully convinced by Chapter 10 of BG.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Perfect. I think Arjuna never asked Krishna for proving their supremacy. But, Lord Krishna himself proved his supremacy in Chapter 10 & 11. So, after that Arjuna never required for that question.

Answer (score 2):

According to Srila Prabhupada [BG 11.3](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/11/3/)

"...Now as far as Arjuna is concerned, he is inspired by the statements of Kṛṣṇa, but in order to convince others in the future who may think that Kṛṣṇa is an ordinary person, Arjuna desires to see Him actually in His universal form, to see how He is acting from within the universe, although He is apart from it..."

Answer (score 1):

मत्त: परतरं नान्यत्किञ्चिदस्ति धनञ्जय ।
मयि सर्वमिदं प्रोतं सूत्रे मणिगणा इव ॥ ७ ॥
O conqueror of wealth, there is no truth superior to Me. Everything rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread.
[Bg 7.7]

Also,

सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज ।
अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा श‍ुच: ॥ ६६ ॥Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.
[Bg 18.66]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).